# Mismatched parenthesis

Tags: vba, libreoffice

I wrote a function for calc to split a cell before a word containing certain characters:

```
Function sidx(inputstr) As Integer
    Dim newString As String
    newString = ""
    Dim last_space_idx As String
    last_space_idx = 0
    Dim l As Integer
    'l = (inputstr.Length - 1) was ported from js on google sheets
    l = Len(inputstr) - 1
    For i = 0 To l
       If inputstr(i) = " " Then
            last_space_idx = i
       End If
       If ("’aeiou".Indexof( inputstr(i) ) > 0) Then
            sidx = last_space_idx
       End If
    Next i
    sidx = last_space_idx
End Function
```

for some reason libreoffice has trouble parsing this and complains about  mismatched parenthesis or missing Then at the last If statement. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this `vba` or `vb.net`?? `.IndexOf` looks to be `vb.net`...

Comment: Although that should probably be `If ("’āēīōū".Indexof(inputstr(i))) > 0 Then`, moving that parenthesis from outside of `> 0` to inside.

Comment: its vba I'm tying instr

Comment: @OrenBochman I don't think `.IndexOf` exists in VBA. Although I MAY be wrong.

Comment: @dwirony No, you are not wrong.

Comment: Strings are not objects in VBA. You can't call methods on string literals. Also, `EndIf` should be `End If`. In Excel the VBA editor automatically inserts the space, but that might not be the case in whatever you are using.

Comment: IndexOf with .Net accessed method via system collection for arraylist. So, method called on arraylist object.

Comment: @QHarr That just means that there is *some* object which you can create which has `IndexOf()` as a method -- it doesn't mean that it is valid VBA in this context. It is a syntax error here.

Comment: @JohnColeman Agreed. It is wrong for here but thought I'd thrown in that it is used with VBA code as I use it.

Comment: I agree I'm using 
l = ubound(inputstr,1) - 1
but it does not seem to fix the issue, nor 
l = ubound(cstr(inputstr),1) - 1

Answer (score 0):

So thanks everyone for all the help - there are many pitfalls porting javascript to libreoffice vba and the interpreter is not that useful... You spotting most of the issues!
Letter extraction was also broken and as I originally believed the brackets was not the real issue!

For closure here is the working version

```
Function sidx (inputstr As String) As Integer
    Dim newString as String 
    newString = ""
    Dim last_space_idx as String
    last_space_idx = 0
    Dim l as Integer
    l = Len(inputstr) -1
    For i = 0 to l
       letter = Mid(cstr(inputstr),i+1,1)
       If letter =  " " Then 
            last_space_idx = i
       End If
       'If ("’āēīōū".Indexof(inputstr(i))) > 0 Then
       If InStr("\’āēīōū",letter) > 0 Then 
            sidx = last_space_idx
       End If
    Next i
    sidx = last_space_idx
End Function
```

Comment: LibreOffice does *not* use Microsoft VBA.  The language is called [LibreOffice Basic](https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Basic_Help).  It can also be called StarBasic (an old name), OpenOffice Basic or simply Basic.